# How to understand paragraph-start variable regex

Tags: regular-expressions, characters

## Problem

When i evaluate the *paragraph-start* variable in the major mode *lisp-mode*, it has the following value

```
"^L\\|[    ]*$"
```

In emacs the `^L` is displayed in red color so I'm not sure if there is some character in between that I could not be displayed properly.

According to the [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html) *paragraph-start* is a buffer local variable and is set "to specify that only blank lines separate paragrap" in *Lisp mode*. However, I don't see how the regex above matches blank line. I would parse the regex above in the following way:

1. `^L\\`: This matches lines that begin with `L\`, since the anchor `^` indicates start of string or line and `\\` indicates an escaped `\`.
2. `|` indicates an or joining the regex before (1) and after (3).
3. `[    ]*$`: The first part `[    ]` is a character class containing just the space character (why are there multiple space characters in it?). The quantifier `*` indicates that the preceding character class, which is only space, shall be matched zero or more times at the End which is indicated by the anchor `$`.

Furthermore, the emacs (25.2.1) documentation <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `paragraph-start` states that:

> This regexp should match lines that separate paragraphs and should also match lines that start a paragraph

## Question

The regular expression (3) should either match the end of a **any** line, if no white spaces were found, or a string of spaces at the end of each line.

1. *Does (3) match "lines that separate paragraphs"?* If yes, why? If not, what does it mean?

Regular expression (1) should only match a line beginning with `L\` as far as I can see.

2. *Does (1) match "lines that start a paragraph"* If yes, why? If not, what does it mean?

I probably messed up somewhere by misunderstanding either the documentation or the regex. However, a small explanation where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

As a reference for the regex matching i used the online [emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Your main confusion lies in that `^L` isn't a two-characters regexp, it's an ASCII control character (page-break/ FORM FEED), that's why it appears in red in your system.

on #3, if you iterate over the blanks and using `M-x describe-char` you'll notice that it should match either space or tab. Reasons are described in the documentation string:

> Regexp for beginning of a line that starts OR separates paragraphs.
>   This regexp should match lines that separate paragraphs
>   and should also match lines that start a paragraph
>   (and are part of that paragraph).
>
> This is matched against the text at the left margin, which is not necessarily the beginning of the line, so it should never use "^" as an anchor.  This ensures that the paragraph functions will work equally well within a region of text indented by a margin setting.

Comment: Note also that you can type a form feed character with `C-q C-l`

Comment: If you set `print-escape-control-characters` then `^L` will be represented as `\14` instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that `^L` is the form feed character. I also found out that you need to escape `\` in elisp strings hence `\\|` becomes `\|` which is or in emacs regex. Hence the first regex should just match form feed. Why does a line containing form feed separate paragraphs?

Comment: Definition of paragraph varies depending on mode, you should read the manual :<https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Paragraphs.html> where this question and the uses of `paragrapah-start` and `paragraph-separate` are discussed.

Comment: Forgot to mention that ^L is also used to separate sections or jump to another page, both uses match the definition given in the manual. Remember that those variables are customizable.

Comment: Yes, see `C-h v page-delimiter` in the same buffer.  Typically this is a line beginning with a form-feed, and clearly a page-break needs to also be treated as a paragraph-break.  See also `C-h f forward-page` and `backward-page`.